# Symfony 4 multiple injections of HTTP Client to split into an abstract class and two separate classes

Tags: php, symfony, oop

My class was always running on one HTTP client injection but then there become a need for another which has uses different `base_uri` so I assumed that it can be used like written underneath.

```
public function __construct(string $key, HttpClientInterface $client, HttpClientInterface $secondClient)
{
    $this->key = $key;
    $this->client = $client;
    $this->secondClient = $secondClient;
}
```

Same class also has some methods that are used for certain calculations.

```
public function method1()
{
    $this->makeRequest($this->client, []);
}

public function method2()
{
    $this->makeRequest($this->secondClient, []);
}
```

I was advised to create an abstract class and then another two classes like `Client1` and `Client2` that extend that abstract class.

My idea of that is that the abstract would look something like this:

```
abstract class AbstractClientClass
{
    protected $key;
    protected $client;

    public function __construct($key, HttpClientInterface $client)
    {
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function makeRequest($data): ResponseInterface
    {
        return $this->client->request(...);
    }

}
```

So I assume `method1` would go to `Client1` class and the same with `method2` and `Client2` class. But does it make sense to name it a client anymore? And is this really the right way?
Also, how would I use these clients in my main class? Would I just instantiate both of them in `construct` method? Any suggestions or related documentation that could help me?

Comment: You can use Scoping Client https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#scoping-client

Comment: @Artem That is what I am doing. I am scoping two clients and injecting them both in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really explain what are the conditions for the switch from one client to another. You must SOMEHOW know whether to use one, or the other. How do you know?

If the only moment you do know whether to use client1 or client2 is at runtime then well.. create an if.

`if($condition1){ $client1->...} else{ $client2-> }`

I would probably inject both clients into your own custom class `ClientFactory.php`
and give that client factory the knowledge how to decide when to use which

Assuming you CAN KNOW whether to use client1 or client2 from the `$request` data then do it like so
e.g.

```
class SomeController{

  public function index(ClientFactory $cf, Request $request){
    $client = $cf->getClient($request->toArray() /* if that works */);
  }
```

you'd need to define the ClientFactory as a service as well I guess to be able to inject it.